# How to switch APL documents in Alexa without returning a new document?

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-presentation-language

When developing my Alexa skill, Each time I want to change user's screen in my skill (using APL), I return a new APL document. However, this is slow because it must load the document each time.

Is there a better way to do this instead of returning a new document each time?

I have found some info on this but struggle to find an answer in Python.
Below is the code I use to return a new document.

```html
datasources = _load_apl_document("recipe_output_data.json")
        if get_supported_interfaces(handler_input).alexa_presentation_apl is not None:
            handler_input.response_builder.add_directive(
                RenderDocumentDirective(
                    token="recipe_output",
                    document=_load_apl_document("recipe_output_APL.json"),
                    datasources=datasources
                )
        )
```

Comment: Please don't use the tag [tag:apl] for Alexa-related questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to load the document every time then you can use pager in the apl document. Make a pager container and keep all your screens in items. And on user action do not send the document again and instead send apl command to switch between pages. Refer [this](https://developer.amazon.com/en-GB/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-commands.html#:%7E:text=Commands%20are%20messages%20that%20change,Presentation.) for pager and apl commands